# getSheetValues not returning data Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The log for my script returns no information. I've copy-pasted this script with minimal changes from this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310154/how-to-get-an-array-of-values-from-the-column-of-a-spreadsheet). I confirmed the content from the thread in from the [relevant google scripts manual](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetValues%28Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29). Can someone shine some light on this problem?

```
  function myFunction() 
  {
    function stripArray(values) 
    {
      return values.filter(function(d) 
      {
        return d.length && d[0] !== '';
      });
    }

   function testSheet()
    {
      var ssId="1kRdKGDQJXxCW2q1HPclWcpsOpI1BJPvAlMjvLSX6JvY";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var values = sheet.getSheetValues(3, 2, 21, 23);
      Logger.log(values);
      Logger.log(stripArray(values));

    }

  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `stripArray(values)` and `testSheet()` should be seperate functions. Try This code below:

```
function stripArray(values) 
{
   return values.filter(function(d) 
   {
      return d.length && d[0] !== '';
   });
}

function testSheet()
    {
      var ssId="1kRdKGDQJXxCW2q1HPclWcpsOpI1BJPvAlMjvLSX6JvY";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Announcements");
      var values = sheet.getSheetValues(3, 2, 21, 23);
      Logger.log(values);
   Logger.log(stripArray(values));

    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: For this you have to call function testSheet()

Comment: The script you suggest here splits the script into two seperate functions inside the run menu of the google scripts app. If I run stripArray from the drop-down menu it doesn't work correctly, but if I run testSheet it does indeed work!

THANKS! I never would have thought to do this. Can you offer me an explanation as to why it works like this?

Comment: For the  stripArray(values)  function you have to pass a values array, so you cannot execute that function by selecting it from the drop-down and run it. As you are calling that function from the testSheet() function with some values in the values array, it works properly. Hope that explains your question.